# Mouse become text on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, mouse

I hope you are **fine**.

Here is my problem, I am trying to make an effect where when the user hovers an image, the mouse becomes text. Currently the only solution I found is to create a custom mouse for EACH image and have each class/img have its own mouse/text.
This is not great because it doesn't fit well in responsive and it's not great in terms of code.
Do you have an idea?

Here is a site that uses this effect:
[Waka Waka by Mouthwash](https://wakawaka.world/furniture)

See you and thanks in advance,
Léo

Comment: Please post your solution in a working/minimal/easy to read code, so we can provide suggestions/optimization for it. This website is not for asking other people code for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must first in the HTML create a div where you place both the image and the text that will appear when hovering. On the CSS, make sure the text has absolute positioning. Then use JavaScript to attach the div with the text to the position of the cursor.

```js
function createTextCursor(event){
  let el = document.getElementById("hoveringText");
    el.style.top = event.clientY + "px";
    el.style.left = event.clientX + "px";
}

document.getElementById("main").addEventListener('mousemove', createTextCursor);
```

```css
#main:hover > #hoveringText {
  display : block;
}

#hoveringText {
  position: absolute;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
  display: none;
}

#main{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  cursor: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" onmousemove="createTextCursor(event)">
  <img alt="" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" />
  <div id="hoveringText">text cursor</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello ! Thank you for your fast answer. Your code works well but I have a little problem. Sometimes the text and the cursor are shifted a few dozens of pixels, we can see it in your code, do you know how I can adjust that? 

Thanks in advance

Comment: @LéoMaubert I've edited it. See if that solves the problem. I had to make the #main div have the same width and height as the image to make sure the text only appears when hovering the image.